# How to Fix Row Limits Export, Google analytics to R

Tags: r, google-api, google-analytics-api

Hi I'm using GoogleAnalyticsR to import my data from Google Analytics but I'm having a problem because it only downloads 1,000 rows from a total of 1,000,000.

Any advice how to download all 1,000,000?

Here's my code!

```
df1 <- google_analytics_4(my_id, 
                      date_range = c("2016-05-13", "2017-05-13"),
                      metrics = c("pageviews"),
                      dimensions = c("pagePath"))
```

Comment: You need to look in to pagination you can only request 10000 rows at a time.  look for pageToken

Answer (score 0):

By default it gets 1000 rows, if you set `max = -1` in your call it gets everything:

```
df1 <- google_analytics_4(my_id, 
                      date_range = c("2016-05-13", "2017-05-13"),
                      metrics = "pageviews",
                      dimensions = "pagePath",
                      max = -1)
```